# Why does getkeydown fire several times? (Unity, c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I am trying to teach myself C# and Unity knowledge via [this course over on Udemy.com](https://www.udemy.com/unitycourse/learn/v4/overview).
In one of the first examples a very basic text adventure was created. 
Now starting from scratch, I have used the same game structure used there, trying to recreate my own version of this, I've run into a problem:

```
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)
```

gets activated multiple times in a row and I haven't found the solution in hours.
Here's the relevant parts of the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class TextEngine : MonoBehaviour {
public Text myText; 
private int oxygen;


private enum States
{
    wakeup, window_0, room_1, corridor_1, corridor_left,
    corridor_right, corridor_right_left, locked_supply_door,
    damaged_supply_door, supply_door_keypad
} 
private States myState;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {        
    myState = States.wakeup;                                           
}





// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    // Basic gameplay loop:
    //if myState equals scenario a, then call method a
    if (myState == States.wakeup)                   wakeup();
    if (myState == States.room_1)                   room1();
    if (myState == States.corridor_1)               corridor_1();
    if (myState == States.corridor_right)           corridor_right();
    if (myState == States.locked_supply_door)       locked_supply_door();

}



void wakeup()
{
    oxygen = 100;
    myState = States.room_1;
}


void room1()
{
    myText.text = "Oxygen Level: " + oxygen + "\n\nYou wake up. Press W to see Window. "
                    +"Press C to go down the Corridor.";

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        myState = States.window_0;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        myState = States.corridor_1;
    }


}




void corridor_1()
{

    myText.text = "Oxygen Level: " + oxygen + "\n\nYou walk the corridor to the end."
                 + "You can turn Left or Right.\nFrom the Left you hear two gun shots!"
                 +"\nFrom the Right side comes an eerie silence."
                 + "\n\nPress L to turn Left, R to turn Right. Press B to go Back.";
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
        myState = States.corridor_left;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        print("R1");
        myState = States.corridor_right;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
    {
        print("B");
        myState = States.room_1;
    }
}



void corridor_right()
{

    myText.text = "Oxygen Level: " + oxygen + "\n\nAnother T-junction!\n"
                 + "You can turn Left or Right.\nFrom the left you still hear nothing."
                 + "\nFrom the Right side you hear a deep and frightening buzz!"
                 + "\n\nPress L to turn Left, R to turn Right. Press B to go Back.";
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
        myState = States.corridor_right_left;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        print("R2");
        myState = States.locked_supply_door;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
    {
        print("B");
        myState = States.corridor_1;
    }

}





void locked_supply_door()
{
    myText.text = "Oxygen Level: " + oxygen + "\n\nYou stand in front of a rusty metal door. You step closer. At eye-level there is a dusty sign, "
                 + "barely readable. You wipe off the dust. It reads: 'Supply Room'. Maybe you can find some Oxygen tanks and "
                 + "some communication devices in there?"
                 + "\n\nPress S to Search for a handle."
                 + "\n\nPress R to Ram the door, it looks weak!\n\n"
                 + "Press B to go Back.";
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        myState = States.supply_door_keypad;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        print("R3");
        myState = States.damaged_supply_door;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
    {
        print("B2");
        myState = States.corridor_1;
    }
}
```

}

What I expect to happen:

1. The game starts. 
   `myState = States.wakeup;` gets initalized.
2. `wakeup()` is called, `myState = States.room_1;` calls `room1()` via `Update()` and the text displayed on screen.
3. When pressing the C key, `room(1)` calls `myState = States.corridor_1;` which via `Update()` calls `corridor_1()` and the text is display again.

Everything working as expected so far. But now everthing goes wrong.
I expect this behavior:
4.A I press the R key, `"R1"` gets printed and via `myState = States.corridor_right;` the `corridor_right()` is called and **waits** for another key prompt.

But then this happens:
4.B I press the R key, `"R1"` gets printed and via `myState = States.corridor_right;` the `corridor_right()` is called and then **without anymore input** immediately `"R2"` gets printed, `myState = States.locked_supply_door;` is executed, which calls `locked_supply_door()` via `Update()` and then immediately `"R3"` gets printed to the console and then it changes `myState = States.damaged_supply_door;` where it would continue to call a method via `Update()`, but I've not yet implemented that method.

The steps seem to get executed correctly, but that `GetKeyDown` behaves more like `GetKey' and not like itself!

**Why does `GetKeyDown` seemingly get activated multiple times, even when it's supposed to do so only once?**

Most problems the people have seem to call `GetKeyDown`twice, but not what seems several times. 
A common problem seemed to be that the script is attached multiple times somewhere in Unity, which is not the case here: Canvas with Text Field + attaced Script.

If you have made it this far, I want to thank you for the time you already took to help me. 
If only I could solve this problem, I cannot find the solution! My rubber duck also doesn't help me here.

Comment: If you are gonna post a 300 lines of question, please make sure the post all the code.I read this but `supply_room();` function is missing from your code.We can't tell where stuff is going bad if your code is not complete in the case like this.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I cleared up the code and tried to make the minimum viable case which exihibits the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not doing the "update" with **ELSE**, so when you change from one state to another, it will not wait 1 frame to pass, and will directly go other if, because you changed and is correct, you enter the other if, and because a frame didn't pass till the last R was down, it will still say true to that...

So, in your "Update" function, make them with **ELSE IF**, not all **IF**. This way, when you enter one if, when the function inside finished, it will pass 1 frame to re enter.

So change **Update** to this:

```
void Update()
{

    // Basic gameplay loop:
    //if myState equals scenario a, then call method a
    if (myState == States.wakeup)                        wakeup();
    else if (myState == States.room_1)                   room1();
    else if (myState == States.corridor_1)               corridor_1();
    else if (myState == States.corridor_right)           corridor_right();
    else if (myState == States.locked_supply_door)       locked_supply_door();

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple mistake, I can't believe I didn't notice it.

Comment: You are welcome ! Is easy sometimes to forget this kind of "logic"... I am in the same course :P

Comment: Well, then you'll maybe see the 'finished' version soon there on the forums. Thanks again for the quick answer!

Comment: You are welcome :D I forgot to add, you asked here pretty correctly, about info you posted and stuff. Good job !